# InputMask para DisplayFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-masked-input

Utilizo o jQuery Inputmask para adicionar máscaras em meus TextBox. Porém necessito adicionar máscara ao listar esses campos( telefone, cpf, etc). Utilizo o DisplayFor para listar, porém a máscara não funciona com o mesmo.

Codigo em minha View:

```
                Cargo: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sTelefone)
```

Função JavaScript:

```
<script>

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#sTelefone").mask("9999-9999");
});
```

Agora, quando utilizo o TextBoxFor, a máscara funciona normalmente, porém necessito apenas listar os dados em um dataTable, e o textBox não me atende.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sTelefone)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use algo mais simples. Um `ToString()` formatado resolve tudo:

```
@Model.sTelefone.ToString(@"0000\-0000")
```

Não é preciso formatar por JavaScript porque o campo vai aparecer estático.